# Whether or not a float ends in .5. C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, decimal

I want to check whether or not the value of a float ends in .5 or not using an if-else statement if possible. Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Are you possibly trying to [`round`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) the value to the nearest integer?

Comment: Any tolerance on that? How about 0.4999999?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cmath>
…
if (x - std::trunc(x) == .5 || x - std::trunc(x) == -.5)
    …
```

(Note:  `x - std::floor(x) == .5` works everywhere except one case: If `x` is the next representable value greater than -.5, then `std::floor(x)` is -1, and the ideal mathematical result of `x - std::floor(x)` is slightly greater than -.5, but floating-point rounding produces exactly -.5, so `x - std::floor(x) == .5` falsely returns true. And alternative is `std::fabs(x) - std::floor(std::fabs(x)) == .5`.)

Answer (score 0):

> ... to check whether or not the value of a float ends in .5

Use `modf()` to  find the fractional part.

> The `modf` functions break the argument `value` into integral and fractional parts, each of which has the same type and sign as the argument.

```
#include <cmath>

float ipart;  // The integral is found, but not used.
if (std::fabs(std::modf(x, &ipart)) == .5) {
  ;  // value of a float ends in .5
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To get the decimal part of a real number in `c++` we can use `modf()` function contained in `std` namespace (`std::modf()`) in `<cmath>` library. This function will get only the decimal part of a real number of type `float`, `double` or `long double`. To get an absolute value of the decimal part you need to use the `fabs()` function contained in `std` namespace (`std::fabs()`) in `<cmath>` library. You can combine them like this:

```
#include <cmath>

...

std::cout << "The absolute decimal part is: " << std::fabs(std::modf(realNumber, &entirePart));
```

To check if the decimal part of a number is equal to 0.5, you can use a **conditional ternary operator** (`?:`) and store the check result in a bool value or a int value.

> **In this [page](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/) is mentioned and explained the conditional ternary
>   operator (`?:`) with an example:**
>
> The conditional operator evaluates an expression, returning one value
>   if that expression evaluates to true, and a different one if the
>   expression evaluates as false. Its syntax is:
>
> ```
> condition ? result1 : result2;
> ```
>
> If condition is true, the entire expression evaluates to result1, and
>   otherwise to result2.
>
> ```
> 7==5 ? 4 : 3     // evaluates to 3, since 7 is not equal to 5.
> 7==5+2 ? 4 : 3   // evaluates to 4, since 7 is equal to 5+2.  5>3 ? a : b      // evaluates to the value of a, since 5 is greater than 3.
> a>b ? a : b      // evaluates to whichever is greater, a or b.  
> 7==5 ? 4 : 3     // evaluates to 3, since 7 is not equal to 5.
> 7==5+2 ? 4 : 3   // evaluates to 4, since 7 is equal to 5+2.  5>3 ? a : b      // evaluates to the value of a, since 5 is greater than 3.
> a>b ? a : b      // evaluates to whichever is greater, a or b.
> ```

Here are codes that you can use to solve your problem:

> ### Store result in a bool variable:
>
> ```
> #include <cmath>
>
> ...
> // Here you're declaring the real number variable.
> float realNumber = -4.6f;
> // In this variable will be stored the entire part of realNumber variable.
> float entirePart = 0f;
> // Then you create a bool that will be true if the decimal part is equal to 0.5.
> bool check = ( std::fabs(std::modf(realNumber, &entirePart)) == 0.5) ? true : false ;
>
> // result: check = false
> ```
>
> ### Store result in a int variable:
>
> ```
> #include <cmath>
>
> ...
> // Here you're declaring the real number variable.
> float realNumber = -4.6f;
> // In this variable will be stored the entire part of realNumber variable.
> float entirePart = 0f;
> // Then you create a bool that will be true if the decimal part is equal to 0.5.
> int check = ( std::fabs(std::modf(realNumber, &entirePart)) == 0.5) ? 1 : 0 ;
>
> // result: check = 0
> ```

You can get more information about `c++` operators at these links:

[CPlusPlus: Operators.](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/)

[The Conditional (or Ternary) Operator (?:)](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1AUq5Di1/)

[C++ Conditional ? : Operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_conditional_operator.htm)